# Regular expression for series of IPs?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, web

I'm trying to check if the input text is something like that:

```
(IP| IP1, IP2 | IP1, IP2, IP3) and so on .....
```

for example `172.25.1.4` or `172.25.1.4, 172.25.1.5` or
`172.25.1.4, 172.25.1.6, 3.3.3.3`  and so on ... are accepted.

and the space between IPS is not obligate too so:`172.25.1.4,172.25.1.5` is accepted

I don't know what to use as a pattern:

```
var pattern = theCorrectPattern

if (!pattern.test(id1) && id1.value!="") {

    document.getElementById("id").innerHTML="<p style='color:red'>not correct</p>";

}

else

{
    document.getElementById("id").innerHTML="<p></p>";

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's build this up in pieces.  First, we need a regex for an individual octet (one of the four parts of the IP).  The number can go from 0 to 255.  How can we accomplish this with regex?

For the 0-199 case we can have a simple regex that allows an optional 0 or 1 followed by at least one but no more than two digits in the range 0-9:

```
/[01]?[0-9]{1,2}/
```

Now, we need to handle the 200-255 case.  This is a tad more complex; for example, 249 is valid but 259 is not.  So, we have another pattern that requires a 2, followed by one digit in the range 0-4, followed by one digit in the range 0-9.  This handles the 200-249 case:

```
/2[0-4][0-9]/
```

Finally, we need a pattern to handle the final 250-255 case, which should be fairly obvious:

```
/25[0-5]/
```

Let's string these together into one regex that we can use for our octet:

```
/([01]?[0-9]{1,2}|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))/
  ^ 0-199 case    ^ 200s
                     ^ 200-249 ^ 250-255
```

A bit unwieldy, perhaps, but it works.  Let's stash this away to use in our upcoming patterns.

```
var octetPattern = "([01]?[0-9]{1,2}|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))";
```

Now, we need a pattern that will handle four of these, separated by periods.  We do this by matching one octet, and then matching 3 of (period, octet).

```
var ipPattern = octetPattern + "(\\." + octetPattern + "){3}";
```

Almost there.  Our final pattern matches an IP followed by zero or more of (comma, optional whitespace, IP):

```
var ipGroupPattern = ipPattern + "(, *" + ipPattern + ")*";
```

Now we construct a RegExp object out of it, using the anchor characters.  (Without them, the pattern would match any text that *contains* an IP group; we want to match only if the *complete text* matches.)

```
var pattern = new RegExp("^" + ipGroupPattern + "$");
```

All of this results in this lovely mess:

```
/^([01]?[0-9]{1,2}|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))(\.([01]?[0-9]{1,2}|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))){3}(, *([01]?[0-9]{1,2}|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))(\.([01]?[0-9]{1,2}|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))){3})*$/
```

([See it run](http://jsfiddle.net/af6504j9/2/).)

Comment: Ugh.. another regex dump answer. It's obvious the OP doesn't know basic regex, so they wont understand how or why this works, and if it doesn't work, they wont know how to fix it.

Comment: @SterlingArcher I'm in the process of drafting an explanation.

Comment: @SterlingArcher I've updated the answer with an explanation as well as corrected some invalid matches (it would accept 299 as an octet).

Comment: Bet, now that's a quality answer!